# Override binary << operator on struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to do an override on a simple struct like this:

```
struct Node {
    int data1;
        int data2;

    ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const Node &n)
    {
       o << "(a: " << data1 << ", b: " << data2 << ")";
       return o;
    }
};
```

Im getting: error C2804: 'operator <<' too many parameters

So, if i remove the second parameter:

```
    ostream& operator<<(ostream &o)
```

Then i get: Error: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type  'const Node'

What is coming on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, ...)` needs to be a free function.

Move it outside the class and it will work.

The reason it is so is because defining `operator<<(std::ostream&)` (or other binary operators) inside the class implies that object is the LHS operand.  You would have to write smth crazy like:

```
Node << std::cout;
```

Comment: Or declare it as a `friend` and access `data1` and `data2` through `n`.

Comment: You would only make it a `friend` function if it needs to access private data fields of the class. Otherwise, it unnecessarily violates encapsulation. @user

Comment: @CodyGray I think he may have been refereing to Barton-Hackman (sic) trick

Answer (score 4):

`operator<<` needs two operands. There are two ways to define an `operator<<` overload function between two types.

1. As a member function. That's how `operator<<` overloads between `std::basic_ostream` and some of the basic types are defined. When you use `std:cout << 10;`, it gets resolved to the overload operator `std::basic_ostream<char>::operator<<(int)`

   When you define it as member function, the LHS of the operator is an instance of the class. The RHS of the operator is the argument to the function. That's why when you define it as member function, it can only have one argument.
2. As a free function. That's how `operator<<` overloads between `std::basic_ostream` and custom types are defined. These functions must have two arguments. The first argument is the LHS of the operator and the second argument is the RHS of the operator.

   For this reasons, you have to define `operator<<` overload between `std::ostream` and your class as a free function, with `std::ostream&` as the first argument type and `Node const&` as the second argument type.

   ```
    std::ostream& operator<<(std:ostream& os, Node const& node);
   ```

At times like these, I wish the standard library had implemented a function:

```
template <typename T>
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const& t)
  {
     return t.serialize(os);
  }
```

Then, any class could provide the function

```
std::ostream& serialize(std::ostream& os) const;
```

and be ready to be used like all the basic types with `std::ostream`.